# How to assign a category based on a number range?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, lookup

I'm having a problem with Excel.

In my game, the hero has max level, which determines by its rarity. So a Common Hero can get only to level 40

I want to determine which rarity a hero is based on its level (for example: Level 1 is Common, Level 45 is Rare, Level 60 is Epic, etc.)

[image]

===========================

Here's what I tried, using VLOOKUP
1. Adding a sub column next to "Level Max", the value is the same as "Rarity"

2. Use the formula : `=VLOOKUP(D3,$B$2:$C$13,2,TRUE)`

3. However, the result is not what I expected, if player level is less than 40, it returns "`N/A`", if player level is, for example, 45, it returns "`Common`" (it should be Rare)

[image]

Comment: Try `=XLOOKUP(D3:D4,B:B,A:A,,1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using <kbd>INDEX( )</kbd> & <kbd>MATCH( )</kbd> functions.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>F3</kbd>

```
=INDEX($C$2:$C$13,MATCH(1,1/(E3<=$B$2:$B$13),0))
```

---

Alternative approach using <kbd>LAMBDA( )</kbd> helper function <kbd>MAP( )</kbd> with <kbd>XLOOKUP( )</kbd> the following formula will spill dynamically

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>F3</kbd>

```
=MAP(E3:E4,LAMBDA(m,XLOOKUP(1,1/(m<=B2:B13),C2:C13)))
```

---

Approach using <kbd>VLOOKUP( )</kbd> function

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>F3</kbd>

```
=VLOOKUP(TRUE,IF({1,0},E3<=B$2:B$13,C$2:C$13),2,0)
```

---

All the above screenshots updated (initial update was from Android Mobile MS365) and formulas applied in **MS365** Version Desktop Excel App, hence <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> was not required while exiting the edit mode, but it is needed based on ones excel version. Below screenshot shows formula applied in **Excel 2010** using <kbd>VLOOKUP( )</kbd> and <kbd>INDEX( )</kbd> & <kbd>MATCH( )</kbd>

---

With <kbd>INDEX( )</kbd> & <kbd>MATCH( )</kbd> so it should work in **Excel 2013** as well, but remember to hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> (***see those curly brackets at the end***)

[image]

---

With <kbd>VLOOKUP( )</kbd> in Excel 2010 so it should work in Excel 2013 as well, but remember to hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

[image]

---

Last but not least, using <kbd>LOOKUP( )</kbd> function is just succinct and you dont need to hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> while exiting the edit mode, only you have to create an additional column for **Level Min**

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>F3</kbd>

```
=LOOKUP(E3,$A$2:$C$13)
```

---

Some ***facts*** about <kbd>LOOKUP( )</kbd> Function:

- Availability since **1979**, first appeared in **VisiCalc**
- While <kbd>VLOOKUP( )</kbd> appeared in **1983**, which is actually the successor to the original lookup style function.
- <kbd>LOOKUP( )</kbd> was created to help with **Bob Frankston's** tax return. You can read about it **[here](https://rmf.vc/implementingvisicalc)**.

---

Also adding the approach with **Modern Excel Function** which I have shown earlier using <kbd>MAP( )</kbd> & <kbd>XLOOKUP( )</kbd> showing only with <kbd>XLOOKUP( )</kbd> so it may be a useful resource for others seeking for a solution.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>F3</kbd>

```
=XLOOKUP(E3:E4,A2:A13,C2:C13,,-1)
```

---

Or,

• Formula used in cell <kbd>G3</kbd>

```
=XLOOKUP(E3:E4,B2:B13,C2:C13,,1)
```

---

Comment: Thanks @Mayukh

I think there's a mistake, I used INDEX & MATCH and it gives this N/A error
https://prnt.sc/NWOBd4Oxiuk6

Also the Vlookup doesn't give the result just like yours
https://prnt.sc/z_91f5NpG-BP

I'm using Excel 2013, it doesn't have XLOOKUP unfortunately

Comment: Hi @DuyHoangNguyen I forgot to mention since I thought you might be using MS365. As you are using Excel 2013 you need to hit `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`ENTER` while exiting the edit mode.

Comment: @DuyHoangNguyen I have updated the possible ways, also if you use `LOOKUP()` function you dont need any other function, it works with any version of Excel, since it is there since VisiCalc in 1979.

Comment: Just used CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER and works like a charm. Thank you so much for your detailed answer

Comment: Absolutely Sounds Good =)